# ordernumbers only odd numbers

Tags: magento2, orders

I will get for an order number only odd numbers.
How can I change it that I will get all numbers.
For example I will get only numbers like:
#000000551
#000000553
#000000555
.....

My table looks like:
[image]

I use always step 1. So I think everything is o.k. in the table or what should I change there?

Hope someone can still help me there.
kindly regards

Answer (score 1):

Do you have only 1 DB? If yes, check this article for more details, but, basically, you can check the `step` values inside the `sales_sequence_profile` table. I suspect it is 2 in your case. Change is to 1, and it should be fine now.

https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-change-increment-id-prefix-suffix-start-value-step-pad-length-of-order-invoice-creditmemo-shipment/

Comment: I have one DB but I have in the table in each row step 1. Hope someone can still help me. Kindly regards

Comment: Hope someone can still help me here with this problem. Kindly regards

Comment: Maybe I must change the prefix of profile_id 9 from 2 to 1?